# Error Reading JMS queue on Solace

Tags: java, solace

I have a queue on Solace, where i am able to write data to queue.
But getting error while reading data from queue.

Below is the error i am getting.
Any idea what could be the issue.

---

```
Oct 26, 2017 3:13:54 PM com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel close
INFO: Channel Closed (smfclient 6)
Oct 26, 2017 3:13:54 PM com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.flow.BindRequestTask execute
INFO: Error Response (403) - Permission Not Allowed
```

> javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: Error creating consumer - access
>   denied (Permission Not Allowed)

---

Answer (score 2):

The issue is likely that the client is not the owner of the queue and the queue is configured with "Read Only" or "No Access" for its permission level.

The queue's permission level defines the level of access given to consuming clients that are not defined as the owner of the queue.

To resolve this issue, you can edit the queue's permission level to "Consume", "Modify-Topic", or "Delete". Note that you will need to disable the queue before making these changes.

Comment: thanks a lot Alexandra, working fine post permission change.